# how to use the commandLine and JavaFx at the same time

Tags: java, javafx

It's a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Is there a Way in java to have the command line active and still have a JavaFX stage screen.

Currently, when I show my stage the command line isn't functioning.

Comment: Can you please provide code that shows your efforts on solving the problem?

Comment: Which command line? What do you expect it to do? What have you tried and in what way did it not succeed?